# using Substring in Xpath expression in apache camel: error

Tags: xml, xpath, substring, apache-camel

I would like to sort out some node of an SOAP header to perform sticky load balancing in apache camel.
And for that I am using xpath
and my xpath expression looks something like this:

```
.loadBalance().sticky(xpath("substring(string(/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Header']/*[local-name()='ReplyTo']/*[local-name()='ReferenceParameters']/*[local-name()='ServiceGroupId']/text()), 10)"))
.to(BE1,BE2);
```

But when i execute it, i get an error: `org.apache.camel.builder.xml.InvalidXPathExpression: Invalid xpath:`

So I thought there should be some problem with my xpath expression, hence i created a small java program that would do the same thing and perform the same action.
And with java I got the desired element from my xml. But I am getting this error in apache camel.

Am i doing anything wrong here? any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Your XPath is correct, works for me in http://p3rl.org/XML::XSH2

Comment: If the number of nodes returned by the xpath are more than 1, then i think string() and substring() functions will be failing

Comment: @KaipaMSarma, No, whenever the argument is a node-set, these functions operate on the string value of the first node.

Comment: I already told you to use the resultType(String.class) on the Camel mailing list. This will ensure the xpath return is a String type, and not a XML type (Node, NodeList or wtf it returns).

Comment: @ClausIbsen I tried doing that but I get an error: The method xpath(String) in the type BuilderSupport is not applicable for the arguments (String, 
 Class<String>)

Comment: @ClausIbsen I got it working, thanks for your support and help. :)

Comment: Can you post your solution, and mark this as answered? This can help people in the future who read this and looks for a solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working!

The code is as follow:

```
.loadBalance().sticky(env.xpath("substring(string(/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Header/wsa:ReplyTo/wsa:ReferenceParameters/axis2:Serv‌​iceGroupId/text()), 10)", String.class)) 
          .to(BE1,BE2);
```

Where env is my namespace and BE1 and BE2 are backend servers!